# the CircularProgressIndicator when loading web page using flutter_inappwebview not working in ios

Tags: flutter, dart

> I tried to add a CircularProgressIndicator while waiting to the web
> page to load, and then the page display and the circular indicator
> dosen't show on screen. in android device is worked but in ios device
> not working , why ?
>
> my code :

```
dynamic progress = 0 ;
return SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                actions: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                    onPressed: _onBack,
                  ),
                ],
                //actions: <Widget>[NavigationControlls(_controller.future)],
              ),
              body: new Builder(builder: (BuildContext contixt) {
                return Container(
                  child: Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      WillPopScope(
                        onWillPop: _onBack,
                        child: SafeArea(
                          child: InAppWebView(
                            initialUrl: url,
                            onWebViewCreated:
                                (InAppWebViewController webViewController) {
                              controller = webViewController;
                            },
                            onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller,
                                String url) {},
                            onProgressChanged:
                                (InAppWebViewController controller,
                                    int progress) {
                              setState(() {
                                this.progress = progress / 100;
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: _buildProgressBarIOS()),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              })),
        );
```

> _buildProgressBarIOS() method :

```
Widget _buildProgressBarIOS() {
    if (progress != 1.0) {
      return Container(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            CupertinoActivityIndicator(
              animating: false,
              radius: 50,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
    return Container();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function which returns your web view and then do like this :-

```
body: new Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
   return progress == 100.0 ? yourInAppWebView() : circularIndicator();
}
```